# Issue displaying modal on google map marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a map with pins that show a modal when someone clicks the pin, I have the pins working but for some reason the modal does not display when I click.  Below is the code I am using, any help appreciated.

The MapWithPins renders the Google Map and I tried to put the onclick function here, but to no avail. The LocationPin is to render the pins on the google map and where I placed the onClick to show the modal, also to no avail.

MapWithPins.jsx

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import LocationPin from "./LocationPin";
const MapWithPins = ({ locations, zoomLevel }) => {
  <div className="map">
    <div className="w-full h-[90vh]">
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_TOKEN }}
        defaultCenter={locations[0]}
        defaultZoom={zoomLevel}
        options={{ disableDefaultUI: true, zoomControl: true, minZoom:4, maxZoom:18 }}
   >

        { locations.map((location, index) => (
          <LocationPin
           lat={location.lat}
           lng={location.lng}
           text={location.title}
           key={index}
          />

   ))}
      </GoogleMapReact>
 </div>
</div>
);
}
```

LocationPin.jsx

```
import {Icon} from '@iconify/react';
import locationIcon from '@iconify/icons-mdi/map-marker';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const LocationPin({text}) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
       <div className="flex items-center w-[180px] text-[#00009E]">
          <Icon icon={locationIcon} className="text-6xl" onClick={() => setShowModal(true) } />
          <p className="text-sm">{text}</p>
       </div>

       { showModal && (
            <>
               <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
              <div className="relative w-auto my-6 mx-auto max-w-3xl">
                 <div className="border-0 rounded-lg shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full bg-white outline-none focus:outline-none">
                  <div className="flex items-start justify-between p-5 border-b border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-t">
                    <h3 className="text-3xl font-semibold">
                      Modal Title
                    </h3>
                    <button
                      className="p-1 ml-auto bg-transparent border-0 text-black opacity-5 float-right text-3xl leading-none font-semibold outline-none focus:outline-none"
                      onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
                    >
                      <span className="bg-transparent text-black opacity-5 h-6 w-6 text-2xl block outline-none focus:outline-none">
                        ×
                      </span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                   <div className="relative p-6 flex-auto">
                    <p className="my-4 text-slate-500 text-lg leading-relaxed">This is some text.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex items-center justify-end p-6 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b">
                    <button
                      className="text-red-500 background-transparent font-bold uppercase px-6 py-2 text-sm outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
                    >
                      Close
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </>
         )
       }
    </>

  );

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox the reproduces the issue you are experiencing? What's also the error on the console?

Comment: There is no error on console - will try to put on codesandbox latdr